# Program accessible only to super user

Tags: sudo, latex

I installed TeXLive through the .iso file provided in the website. To check the installation I tried `tex --version` and it returned something like `The program 'tex' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install texlive-binaries.`. However, if I try the same thing as a super user, it displays the version of TeX installed.

How to make this program accessible to normal user?

Note: According to the instructions, I had to update ~/.bashrc file with PATH, MANPATH and INFOPATH as a super user. Does this have anything to do with the program being accessible only to the super user?

Comment: Is the ~/.bashrc in /root or in /home/user? If it is in /root, copy that .bashrc to your home folder. Try typing in the absolute path of the tex program (maybe /usr/share/tex/tex or something like that).

Comment: Which website? What instructions?

Comment: @Zzzach... The ~/.bashrc was in /root. Copied it to my home folder and it works fine now! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Close this thread if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ZZzach... indicated, the ~/.bashrc file was in the root folder i.e /root, rather than the home folder /home/user. This is the reason why the commands were read while I was running the terminal as root, and not as a normal user.

The solution was to copy the file to /home/user folder.